# how to prevent race conditions in my case

Tags: android, multithreading

I am doing an android app and I have an UI to show some data received from the server. The data is saved in the db in a controller.
When the app is started, this is what it is doing:

1. the controller instance is initialized on the Ui thread, it is singleton. The initialization is lightweighted. The UI will call the controller method to get the data saved in memory and show it.
2. having a worker thread to execute some controller method to read the data from db and save it in the cache in memory and notify UI after get it.
3. whenever there is some new data, the server will send a push to the client where an intentservice is started and the controller talks to the server to get the data and update the cache and after it completes, it notifys UI.

So the question is the 2 and 3, since both are running in different threads, so in order to make sure the db must be read and save in cache first, I have a flag in 3) so that before writing the new data in the memory, I always check the flag first. It will work but since I can foresee there will be more operations on the cache probably cross different threads and I really don't want to add the flag checking in all such places, so do we have any pattern/way to make sure the 2) always happens first?

sorry that I didn't find any similar post on it. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

ok do one thing when your statement 2 is complete the execution at the last line of code call a broadcast receiver and inside onRecieve() method which is inside the BroadCastReceiver execute the statement 3.

Comment: the 3) which is asking the server to get the new data. And that is triggered by the GCM. And that will also need a flag to tell inside the onReceive() to tell when to ask the server, right? If that is true, then that would be very similar to use a flag to check the db if that is loaded or not before asking the server.

Comment: No i think there is no need to check flag inside onReceive() .But you should launch the broadcast when you get complete step 2 and ready to execute step 3.

Comment: the 3) is to only talk to the server when the GCM is received and we never know when the gcm is received. so how to make sure the 2) is complete before 3)?

Comment: I don't know about GCM but ya there must some method which triggered when receiving data from GCM is complete.